# Need a sort of a reverse CATransform3d

Tags: ios, objective-c, frame, bounds, catransform3d

I have two views (one is inside the another one).

The superview is "fullscreen" (it means it has `frame == screenBounds` and `layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity`). So it looks like a rect.

The subview has the same frame but also has a defined transform which contains translation, rotation, scale and perspective. So it looks like a trapezium.

Additionally in my case the parent and the child frames don't intersect. So the parent view looks like a rect and the child one looks like a trapezium.

Which one complex transform should I apply to these both views to make the subview "fullscreen"? (after this transform the parent view will become a trapezium vice versa)

If it would be more clear for you I mean this transform:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bjPQG43c_pE&t=1m00s

It occurs when you select one from safari pages 3D list.

Comment: by 'perspective' do you mean your transform contains shear?

Comment: I mean the following: http://static.iconsplace.com/icons/preview/maroon/table-256.png. The tabletop is rect but when you see on this picture it looks like a trapezium.

Comment: do you have a github project with this? Or at least the matrix you are dealing with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your transform matrix of your inner view only contains `affine` transformations**(i.e translate, rotate, scale, reflect, shear)** all you need to do is `invert` your inner view's transformation matrix to transform it to the bounds of the outerview, assuming its frame is the same as the outerview's.

```
CATransform3D innerViewTransform = innerView.layer.transform;
outerView.layer.transform = CATransform3DInvert(innerViewTransform);
```

**Note:** transform is applied around the `-anchorPoint` property. FYI.

Comment: Maybe it is correct but I can't check it because your method doesn't take into account "perspective" transform (element `m34`). So I don't know how to apply anchor point other than default.

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov don't worry about anchor point for now. `Perspective` is handled by the `projection system` not by the object itself. There could be a `perspective` projection or `orthographic` projection and the objects in the scene are oblivious to it. As in, 1 scene could be rendered using both perspective and orthographic modes.

Comment: I mean If I apply this transform without of taking into account `perspective` then the view is not fullscreen only but it remains trapezium not rect. Could you explain how does it handled by the projection system. I took `iCarousel` as an example and they handle the `perspective` by themselves. I tried other ways but found no way how to change rect into trapezium.

Comment: the geometry operation you wish to apply is called `shear`. Remember `perspective` only affects objects with depth. That table was in 3D, it had depth, the 2D UIView does not. To understand the graphics pipeline take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_pipeline#Projection_transformation)

Comment: I think you are mistaken: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Shear.html   . And look at the perspective: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/perspective   . The main difference is shear has one direction vector for all the points. Finally  `perspective` doesn't mean 3D objects only but also 2D objects in 3D space. But anyways it has not influence on the solution.